# Pulling column from sheet 2 and importing into another workbook

Tags: google-sheets

So I need to find the formula to pull a column out of one page of my Google Docs spreadsheet and insert it into a separate workbook.

Here are some more details: all rows from column C (part number) from sheet 2, workbook 1 and insert it into sheet 1 of workbook 2 (under column C "part number").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Formula gives you the perfect solution:

```
=ImportRange("0Anrm0HgYyzzRdGR3TWpBelFCenJYM01ZUDZsaWNsTkE";"Sheet2!C3:C13")
```

Write this formula in the "C3" of your "workbook 2,sheet 1".

Comment: funny, because I deff tried to work that formula ... Iguess there was something that I missed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey @karthik I have another question if you have the time. [Here is the link for its posting](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53182/using-combined-if-then-with-importrange-formula-in-google-docs)