# Using combined IF THEN with IMPORTRANGE formula

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am looking to understand what the correct syntax would be for a formula for a Google Spreadsheets that would use the `IF THEN` function inside of an `IMPORTRANGE` formula.

I want to import all of the part numbers from column `C` of workbook 1, sheet 1,
and stick them into column `C`, sheet 1 or workbook 2

I would like to see about a formula that would *only* pull the cells that have content, while also leaving all the additional blank cells behind.

Comment: If the cell doesn't have content, then it will pull a blank cell. There is no need to specify that in the formula.

Comment: I understand that if the cell is empty it will leave the corresponding cell blank. I was hoping to be able to omit all the empty cells during the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(
   IMPORTRANGE(
     "0Anrm0HgYyzzRdGR3TWpBelFCenJYM01ZUDZsaWNsTkE", 
     "Sheet1!C3:C13"
   ),
   "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 <> ''"
 )

Copy/paste
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("0Anrm0HgYyzzRdGR3TWpBelFCenJYM01ZUDZsaWNsTkE", "Sheet1!C3:C13"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 <> ''")
```

### Explained

The `QUERY` formula will take the dataset obtained from the `IMPORTRANGE` formula and show the first column (`Col1`) only where Col1 has an entry.

### Example

I've added my solution into your file.

### Limitations

QUERY would try to determine character/numeric type of each column. If you have columns that have mixed text and number in cells, with numbers at start, it would be decided as numeric, and text cells replaced with blanks.

Comment: hey @jacob thanks for your help!

Comment: would you also be able to help me with a QUERY formula to pull a column from same workbook, different sheet?

I cant seem to understand it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `=filter(A8:A15,A8:A15<>"")` but replace `A8:A15` with the import.

So `=filter(ImportRange("0Anrm0HgYyzzRdGR3TWpBelFCenJYM01ZUDZsaWNsTkE";"Sheet1!C3:C13"),ImportRange("0Anrm0HgYyzzRdGR3TWpBelFCenJYM01ZUDZsaWNsTkE";"Sheet1!C3:C13")<>"")`